# Problem of Shading between to meshes

Tags: shaders

I don't understand why the 3 pieces (circled) don't seem to be attached to the helmet. Note that it is an Object composed of several Meshes.How can I solve this problem?
Thx a lot.[image]

Comment: I'm guessing this is eevee and not connected means there is AO missing where they are touching. Try using an AO node

Comment: Frederik Steinmetz : Thanks !

Comment: Hi, @scud, doe that mean your question is answered?

Comment: Robin Betts : yes everything is ok. THX a lot !!